# Can we create react-native + Angular Application? And Yes then how?

Tags: angular, angular6, react-native

How to set up Angular project with react-native with android and ios configuration?
give instruction or step to create project?

Answer (score 2):

No. React Native does not support Angular. Have you looked at NativeScript or Ionic?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to use webView(hybrid app).

Load local angular code by react native's webView component. you don't need to create server for angular.

```
react-native-project
│   README.md    
│
└───react
│   
└───angular
```